# Replacing multiple lines in a textfile in VB 2017

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck a little here, what I want to do is read a text file find the lines that contain X= and Y= and change X= to X=1 and Y= to Y=1

So far I got this code

```
    Dim MyPath As String = "C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt"
    Dim Rdr As New StreamReader(MyPath)
    Dim ln As String
    Dim NewFile As New StringBuilder

    ln = Rdr.ReadLine

    Do Until ln Is Nothing

        If ln.StartsWith("X=", "Y=") And ComboBox1.Text = "1" Then ln = "X=1" & "Y=1"
        NewFile.AppendLine(ln)
        ln = Rdr.ReadLine
    Loop

    Rdr.Close()

    File.WriteAllText(MyPath, NewFile.ToString)
    MsgBox("Successfully changed the resolution.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

End Sub
```

So this results to only changing X and leaving Y like it is, is it possible to change the two lines at the same time?

Comment: Call `File.ReadAllLines`, loop through the array and modify each element as required, then call `File.WriteAllLines`.

Comment: Your `If` statement doesn't make any sense.  You would need to use `If...ElseIf` to look for one possible value and then another possible value.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict. It will show you that `ln.StartsWith("X=", "Y=")` will not work. There is no overload of `.StartsWith` that takes `(String, String)`

Comment: @Mary i tried & and using And

Comment: @Chomak Are you saying: if the line starts with "X=" then change it to "X=1"; if the line starts with "Y=" then change it to "Y=1" - that is, the x and y things are on separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it, works as i intended to, which changes both values, thanks everyone for their help :)

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyPath As String "C:\Users\kiko4\AppData\Local\FortniteGame\Saved\Config\WindowsClient\text.txt")
        Dim Rdr As New StreamReader(MyPath)
        Dim ln As String
        Dim ac As String
        Dim NewFile As New StringBuilder

        ln = Rdr.ReadLine
        ac = Rdr.ReadLine
        Do Until ln Is Nothing
            If ln.StartsWith("ResolutionSizeX=") Then ln = "ResolutionSizeX=" + TextBox1.Text
            NewFile.AppendLine(ln)
            ln = Rdr.ReadLine
            If ac.StartsWith("ResolutionSizeY=") Then ac = "ResolutionSizeY=" + TextBox2.Text
            NewFile.AppendLine(ac)
            ac = Rdr.ReadLine
        Loop
        Rdr.Close()
        File.WriteAllText(MyPath, NewFile.ToString)
        MsgBox("Successfully changed the resolution.",  MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going for a different approach when you're stuck... try this :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SR As New StreamReader("C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt")
    Dim Result As String = SR.ReadToEnd()
    SR.Close()

    Dim Lines As String() = Result.Split(Environment.NewLine)

    Dim TestLine As String
    Dim ReplacedLine As String

    For Each line As String In Lines
        TestLine = line
        If TestLine.Contains("X=") Then
            ReplacedLine = TestLine.Replace("X=", "X=" & ComboBox1.Text)
            Result = Result.Replace(TestLine, ReplacedLine)
        ElseIf TestLine.Contains("Y=") Then
            ReplacedLine = TestLine.Replace("Y=", "Y=" & ComboBox1.Text)
            Result = Result.Replace(TestLine, ReplacedLine)
        End If
    Next

    Dim SW As New StreamWriter("C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt")
    SW.Write(Result)
    SW.Close()
End Sub
```

Please feel free to ask about anything you didn't understand.

**Hope that was useful**

Answer (score 0):

Using StreamReaders/Writers is nice and all, and it surely is the best approach
when you are trying to iterate over multiple lines, one by one.
However, in this case this really isn't neccessary, since OP's just trying to replace all occurences within the file, lines do not matter at all.

From a readability/length perspective, something like this would be preferable:

```
    Dim inPath As String = "C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt"
    Dim trText As String = File.ReadAllText(inPath)
    If trText.Contains("X=") AndAlso trText.Contains("Y=") Then File.WriteAllText(inPath, trText.Replace("X=", "X=1").Replace("Y=", "Y=1"))
```

(all text in the file is read and saved as a single string to trText, if trText contains the string to be replaced write the contents of trText with replaced values to the file)

Or, if you are 100% sure that every file passed will contain the search-values, you can even do it in one Line:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt", File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\kiko4\Desktop\text.txt").Replace("X=", "X=1").Replace("Y=", "Y=1"))
```

This one **will** blow up if the file doesn't contain "X=" AND "Y=".